# Como passar parâmetro do tipo object para JSonResult

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

A view sempre recebe o objeto Nulo, por quê ?
Esse é o trecho do código jquery:

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.TBCOMPOSICAOID = 0;
obj.DSCOMPOSICAO = "TESTE";
var TBComposicao = JSON.stringify(obj);

$.getJSON("/Composicao/Novo/", { pComposicao: TBComposicao}, function(data){
  var url = "/Composicao/List";
  window.location.href = url;

}).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
  var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
  alert('erro: ' + err.toString());                                    
});
```

Esse é o método chamado pelo getJson:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Até o momento passar os parâmetros por String me atendeu, daqui pra frente tenho que passar esses parâmetros por objeto, pois o formulário é um cadastro de Funcionário / Endereços:

**Model TBFuncionario**

```
public class TBFuncionario
    {
        public int TBFUNCIONARIOID { get; set; }
        public string MATRICULA { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode=true, DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? DTADMISSAO { get; set; }
        public string NMFUNCIONARIO { get; set; }
        public bool STATUS { get; set; }        
        public string CPF { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TBEndereco> TBEndereco { get; set; }
    }
```

**Model TBEndereco**

```
public class TBEndereco
    {
        [Key]
        public int TBENDERECOID { get; set; }

        public int TBFUNCIONARIOID { get; set; }
        public string LOGRADOURO { get; set; }
        public string NUMLOGRADOURO { get; set; }
        public string COMPLEMENTO { get; set; }
        public string BAIRRO { get; set; }
        public string CEP { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("TBFUNCIONARIOID")]
        public virtual TBFuncionario TBFuncionario { get; set; }
    }
```

Trecho JavaScript que gera o objeto populado de Funcionário/Endereços:

```
//ENVIA DADOS VIA AJAX                
                var i, linhasDaTabela = new Array();
                for (i = 0; i < $('.end_logradouro').length; i++) {

                    linhasDaTabela[i] = new Object(); // ESQUECI ESSA LINHA HEHEHE
                    linhasDaTabela[i].TBFUNCIONARIOID = $('.end_funcionarioid')[i].value;
                    linhasDaTabela[i].LOGRADOURO = $('.end_logradouro')[i].value;
                    linhasDaTabela[i].NUMLOGRADOURO = $('.end_numlogradouro')[i].value;
                    linhasDaTabela[i].COMPLEMENTO = $('.end_complemento')[i].value;
                    linhasDaTabela[i].BAIRRO = $('.end_bairro')[i].value;
                    linhasDaTabela[i].CEP = $('.end_cep')[i].value;
                }

                var funci = new Array();
                funci[0] = new Object();
                funci[0].TBFUNCIONARIOID = 0;
                funci[0].NMFUNCIONARIO = $("#NMFUNCIONARIO").val();
                funci[0].MATRICULA = "12312";
                funci[0].DTADMISSAO = $("#DTADMISSAO").val();
                funci[0].STATUS = false;
                funci[0].CPF = "13500305890";
                funci[0].TBEndereco = linhasDaTabela;

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'Novo',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    type: 'post',
                    tBFuncionario: funci,
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    sucess: function () {
                        alert("Sucesso");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, er) {
                        alert("Ocorreu erro!");
                    }
                });
```

**O Controller que receberá os dados do Funcionário e Endereço:**

```
public JsonResult Novo(TBFuncionario tBFuncionario)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //_IRepositorio.InsereFuncionario(tBFuncionario);
                //return RedirectToAction("List");
            }

            return Json(tBFuncionario, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

O problema é o seguinte:
Quando clico no botão Salvar eu executo o trecho Javascript já citado anteriormente, veja o resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Beleza os dados são gerados conforme o esperado, porém no Controller o objeto retorna vazio:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Realmente não sei mais o que fazer, alguém tem alguma sugestão ??

Comment: Adriano, tente fazer o encode os dados a serem enviados da seguinte forma: `$.param({ pComposicao: TBComposicao})`

Comment: Você pode colocar o código do seu *Controller* na forma de texto na sua pergunta?

Comment: Olá TobyMosque fiz o encode como você disse e houve um avanço, o modelo pComposicao é enviado mas mesmo assim os atributos continuam nulos.

Answer (score 1):

A solução mais imediata que consegui foi passar os parâmetros como texto:

```js
var TBCOMPOSICAOID = $("#TBCOMPOSICAOID").val();
                        

var DSCOMPOSICAO = $("#DSCOMPOSICAO").val();

$.getJSON("/Composicao/Novo/"
    , {
        pTBCOMPOSICAOID: TBCOMPOSICAOID,
        pDSCOMPOSICAO: DSCOMPOSICAO
      }
      , function (data) {
          var url = "/Administrativo/Composicao/List/";
          window.location.href = url;
      }).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
          var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
          alert('erro: ' + err.toString());
      });
```

```c#
public JsonResult Novo(int pTBCOMPOSICAOID, string pDSCOMPOSICAO)
{
    var model = new TBComposicao
    {
        TBCOMPOSICAOID = pTBCOMPOSICAOID,
        DSCOMPOSICAO = pDSCOMPOSICAO
    };

    _IRepositorio.AtualizarComposicao(model);
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Obrigado!